# HBase throughput is so small when requesting put for each item

Tags: hbase

I'm testing throughput of put requests in hbase using Java client.

I found out two way, `Table.put(Put)` / `Table.put(List<Put>)` and made a simple test for each of them.

And there were huge difference between them.

When I make put request for single item, throughput is roughly around 200~300.

but when I first add it in the list and send in bulk, throughput is more than 20,000.

I just used one thread for testing so metric itself, but what I want to know is why requesting put for each item is so slow, when HBase can handle much more than that.

According to our system requirement, making put request for a single item seems more proper way to go. But obviously we'll have more items per seconds than several hundreds.

Is there any suggestions for this? Below is code snippet I used for testing:

```
    Table table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf("test"));

    // put single
    for(int i=0;i<logCount;i++){
        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("basic"), Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("none"));
        table.put(put);
    }

    // put list
    for(int i=0;i<logCount;i++){
        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("basic"), Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("none"));
        puts.add(put);
        if(puts.size()>1000){
            table.put(puts);
            puts.clear();
        }
    }
```